# OS is Windows Server?

Tags: c#, vb.net, operating-system, version

How can I check if my .net application is running on Windows 2003 Server?

Because Buildnumber 5.2 is Windows XP and also windows Server 2003.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724833(v=vs.85).aspx

So I need a different check.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Why, specifically, do you need to check? I think that XP and Server 2003 are basically the same (as far as what they support).

Comment: @Jesse Good: How can I perform this check in vb.bet?

Comment: I don't know vb.net very well, but [here is an example I found](https://gist.github.com/hdyk3118/6899110).

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1):

Okay guys,
I coded something that should detect if the OS is a windows server.
If so, it should return true:

```
    Private ReadOnly Property IsWindowsServer() As Boolean
    Get
        Const VER_NT_WORKSTATION As Byte = &H1
        Const VER_PRODUCT_TYPE As UInteger = &H80
        Const VER_EQUAL As Byte = 1
        Dim osvi As New OSVERSIONINFOEX()
        osvi.dwOSVersionInfoSize = CUInt(Marshal.SizeOf(osvi))
        osvi.wProductType = VER_NT_WORKSTATION
        Dim dwlConditionMask As ULong = VerSetConditionMask(0, VER_PRODUCT_TYPE, VER_EQUAL)
        Return Not VerifyVersionInfo(osvi, VER_PRODUCT_TYPE, dwlConditionMask)
    End Get
End Property

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)> _
Structure OSVERSIONINFOEX
    Public dwOSVersionInfoSize As Integer
    Public dwMajorVersion As Integer
    Public dwMinorVersion As Integer
    Public dwBuildNumber As Integer
    Public dwPlatformId As Integer
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=128)> _
    Public szCSDVersion As String
    Public wServicePackMajor As UInt16
    Public wServicePackMinor As UInt16
    Public wSuiteMask As UInt16
    Public wProductType As Byte
    Public wReserved As Byte
End Structure

<DllImport("kernel32.dll")> _
Private Function VerSetConditionMask(dwlConditionMask As ULong, dwTypeBitMask As UInteger, dwConditionMask As Byte) As ULong
End Function

<DllImport("kernel32.dll")> _
Private Function VerifyVersionInfo(<[In]> ByRef lpVersionInfo As OSVERSIONINFOEX, dwTypeMask As UInteger, dwlConditionMask As ULong) As Boolean
End Function
```

I need someone who can check this on different Windows Servers and check if it returns true or not.
I f you test, please write the OS-Server Build Number or Name here, so I know if it works for different versions ^^

U can check like this:

```
MsgBox(IsWindowsServer())
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this IMO is to use WMI. The `Win32_OperatingSystem` class contains a property `ProductType` which is 1 for workstation OS and 2 or 3 for server OS.

I'm no good at VB.NET, maybe someone else can convert this C# for you:

```
public static bool IsServerOS()
{
    return IsServerOS(Environment.MachineName);
}
public static bool IsServerOS(string computerName)
{
    ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions() { EnablePrivileges = true, Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate };
    ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(string.Format(@"\\{0}\root\CIMV2", computerName), options);
    ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");

    using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query))
    using (ManagementObjectCollection results = searcher.Get())
    {
        if (results.Count != 1) throw new ManagementException();

        uint productType = (uint)results.OfType<ManagementObject>().First().Properties["ProductType"].Value;

        switch (productType)
        {
            case 1:
                return false;
            case 2:
                return true;
            case 3:
                return true;
            default:
                throw new ManagementException();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Environment.OSVersion` only gives you the version of the kernel which is the same in XP and Server 2003, so you can't really tell them apart.

However, as far as I'm concerned, they are almost identical in what features they support. If you tell us why you need to know the difference, what feature you'd like to test, we might be able to help more.